# Jmeter - How to add jmx to the docker file

Tags: jmeter

I am creating a Jmeter docker file. I have my JMX file and csv files checked in to git. Could you please guide me on the command to create the jmx image.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least 2 ways of doing this:

1. [Install git client](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-Installing-Git) (the steps are different depending on Linux distribution you're using in Docker) and perform [`git clone`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone) of the repository
2. Use Docker [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instruction to copy the previously cloned .jmx and csv files from the host machine

Going forward I would recommend updating the question with your [Dockerfile](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/) so we could get idea regarding your approach and underlying image(s) - this way we won't have to do "blind shots" and the chance you will get the answer will be much higher.

In the meantime check out [Make Use of Docker with JMeter - Learn How](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/make-use-of-docker-with-jmeter-learn-how) article, you can use it (at least partially) as the reference for building your own setup.

Comment: Thanks, I have clone the git repository. Below are the steps i have included in my docker file. ENV PATH $PATH:$JMETER_BIN
USER 1001


COPY launch.sh /
COPY xxx.csv $JMETER_BIN

Comment: Could you please confirm if we need to create an other .sh file to specify the .jmx root path on the git? export timestamp=$(date +%Y%m%d_%H%M%S) && \
export script_path=root/Platform/jmeter/jmeterscript.jmx && \
export jmeter_path=root/Platform/jmeter && \

  -n
  -t ${script_path}/Search_API.jmx \
  -l ${jmeter_path}/tmp/result_${timestamp}.jtl \
  -j ${jmeter_path}/tmp/jmeter_${timestamp}.log